# QGIS -- Styles in Oracle DB

Tags: qgis

I created a styles in QGIS then saved it to Oracle DB (logged in as table owner STGGIS). It was successfully saved to Oracle DB is STGGIS schema, when I verify on Oracle DB (STGGIS schema) a table LAYER_STYLES was created. Then I granted the necessary privileges to my normal users: Grant select, update on STGGIS.LAYER_STYLES to GISEDITOR (normal users).

The problem is when I logged in as normal user is QGIS, I can't see the saved styles. Only if I logged-in as the table owner STGGIS the saved styles will appear and be able to use it. How can my normal users (GISEDITOR) can also access the saved styles?